# Como aplicar máscara nesses casos?

Tags: c#, razor

Como colocar máscara no item `@item.CPFCNPJDevedor`?

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.Result)
        {
            <tr>                    
                @if (Permissoes.Where(x => x.Acao == "EditChassiCrvGravame" || x.Acao == "VisualizarChassi").Any())
                { 
                    <td>
                        <a href="">
                            <span class="editar-chassi glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="@item.ContratoId" value-contrato="@item.NumeroContrato"></span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                }
            <td>
                @if (Permissoes.Where(x => x.Acao == "EditarContrato").Any())
                { 
                    <a class="editar-contrato" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="return GetContrato(@item.ContratoId)" data-id="@item.ContratoId">@item.NumeroContrato</a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span>@item.NumeroContrato</span>                        
                }
            </td>
                <td>
                    @item.IdentificadorDocumentoLaserfiche
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.NomeCredor
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.CPFCNPJDevedor
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.StatusContrato
                </td>
                <td>

                    @if (item.Pago == false && ViewBag.HabilitarBoleto && !item.CredorPossuiTCT && Permissoes.Any(x => x.Acao == "Boleto"))
                    {
                        @Html.ActionLink("Gerar boleto", "Boleto", new { contrato = @item.NumeroContrato }, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-print", target = "_blank" })
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @{

            if (item.Baixa)
            {
                if (ViewBag.HabilitarBaixa && Permissoes.Where(x => x.Acao == "BaixaContrato").Any())
                {
                    <a class="autorizar-baixa glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-id="@item.ContratoId">Autorizar Baixa</a>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ViewBag.HabilitarCancelar && Permissoes.Where(x => x.Acao == "CancelaContrato").Any())
                {
                    if (item.Cancelar)
                    {
                        <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick="return ShowCancelar(this);" id="@item.ContratoId">Cancelar</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick="return alert('O contrato não pode ser cancelado devido sua situação atual. Dúvidas, entrar em contato com a equipe registral.'); return false;">Cancelar</a>
                    }
                }
            }

                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Estou supondo que CPF sempre tem 11 números e CNPJ 14 números, e que o tipo de `item.CPFCNPJDevedor` é `String`:

```
@if (item.CPFCNPJDevedor.Length < 14) {
    @Convert.ToUInt64(item.CPFCNPJDevedor.ToString()).ToString(@"000\.000\.000\-00")
} else {
    @Convert.ToUInt64(item.CPFCNPJDevedor.ToString()).ToString(@"00\.000\.000/0000\-00")
}
```

[Veja mais sobre converter um inteiro de 64 bits sem sinal para `String` aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fd69cbc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Rapaz, vou dar uma olhada na sua sugestão, valeu!